# Notepad++ regular expressions and replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a couple of sentences that need processing using regular expressions. They're in a text file and I'm opening it in notepad++.

```
<tag>There are two tags here</tag>
<tag>How am i supposed to
feel when this is happening?</tag>
<tag>I'm not sure.
But oh well<tag>
```

Is it possible to use notepad++'s regular expressions and replace functionality to produce an output like so:

```
<tag>There are two tags here</tag>
<tag>How am i supposed to feel when this is happening?</tag>
<tag>I'm not sure. But oh well<tag>
```

So that sentences that span over two or more lines are joined based on the fact that there is a `>` at the end of the sentence. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `\v(?!<)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
[\r\n]+(?!<)
```

with a space

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IhSwaP/2)

**Explanation:**

- `[\r\n]+` - matches 1+ occurrences of a `\r` or `\n`
- `(?!<)` - **negative lookahead** to validate that the above match is not followed by an opening tag `<`

**Before Replacement with space:**

[image]

**After replacing the matches with space:**

[image]